# Multiple rack apps on nginx + passenger, one as root, the other not...config help

Tags: ruby, nginx, url-rewriting, passenger, rack

So I've got two apps I want to run on a server. One app I would like to be the "default" app--that is, all URLs should be sent this app by default, *except* for a certain path, lets call it `/foo`:

```
http://mydomain.com/        -> app1
http://mydomain.com/apples  -> app1
http://mydomain.com/foo     -> app2
```

My two rack apps are installed like so:

```
/var
  /www
    /apps
      /app1
        app.rb
        config.ru
        /public
      /app2
        app.rb
        config.ru
        /public
    app1 -> apps/app1/public
    app2 -> apps/app2/public
```

(`app1` and `app2` are symlinks to their respective apps' public directories). This is the Passenger setup for sub URIs described here: http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#deploying_rack_to_sub_uri

With the following config I've got `/foo` going to app2:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name mydomain.com;
  root /var/www;
  passenger_enabled on;
  passenger_base_uri /app1;
  passenger_base_uri /app2;

  location /foo {              
    rewrite ^.*$ /app2 last;
  }
}
```

Now, how do I get app1 to pick up everything else? I've tried the following (placed after the `location /foo` directive), but I get a 500 with an infinite internal redirect:

```
location / {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /app1$1 last;
}
```

I hoped that the `last` directive would prevent that infinite redirect, but I guess not. My `/foo` rewrite still works. And I can still go to `http://mydomain.com/app1`.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Just posted there...I'd remove this one if I knew how, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

One way is to create a new `config.ru` file that dispatches the request to the correct app.

```
# /var/www/apps/config.ru
require './app1/app1'
require './app2/app2'

map ('/') { run App1 }
map ('/foo') { run App2 }
```

Of course, this means your apps have to be made in a way that they can live on the same execution space.